# Bootstrap col crea un espacio en blanco al usar height: fit-content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

**Edito para añadir aclaración breve**: El objetivo es conseguir que cuando se apilen los dos `div class="col"`, el de arriba tenga la *altura ajustada a su contenido*, el segundo ocupe el *resto del espacio* y que entre ambos no superen los `100vh`.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando: Tengo un `div` `row` con el alto igual al 100% de la pantalla y dos `div`  `col-lg-8` que quiero que al verse en dispositivos pequeños (cuando las columnas se apilan) la primera tenga el alto limitado a su contenido. Para ello he creado la siguiente media-query:

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
    .full-height > div:first-child{
        height: fit-content;
    }
}
```

Eso reduce el alto del primer `div` exactamente como quiero, pero el segundo no se mueve del sitio ni se estira para cubrir el hueco dejado. Os adjunto un ejemplo aquí:

```css
.full-height{
    min-height: 100vh;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .full-height > div:first-child{
      height: fit-content;
  }
  /* Añado el color rojo de fondo al segundo hijo para enseñar el gap que se crea en medio*/
  .full-height > div:nth-child(2){
        background:red;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row full-height">
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center bg-left" style="background-color:#4982fc;">
        Primer DIV
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 text-center px-0">
        Segundo DIV
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Me gustaría saber alguna manera de hacer que las filas se apilen correctamente porque llevo ya unos días buscando cómo hacerlo y no consigo nada que tenga un funcionamiento consistente.
He intentado usar

- **`height|min-height|max-height: 100%`** en el div de abajo
- **Javascript para mover el div a su sitio**: Lo descarté porque tendría que ejecutarse cada vez que se modifique el tamaño de la pantalla.
- **Usar `min-content` en la media-query**: mismo efecto
- **`margin|padding|height: 0px` en `.full-height > div::after`**: Nada

Comment: Lo que necesitas es que el div rojo quede justo debajo del azul sin ese espacio en blanco, cierto? En vistas moviles

Comment: Exacto. Pero el azul tiene que tener una altura acorde a su contenido, ese es el problema que tengo!

Comment: Si el problema te lo da ese `fit-content` en el alto del primer div, yo creo que lo mejor es quitarlo, y luego, para solucionarlo, en el segundo div, aplicas un `auto 100vh`, esto empuja hacia la parte superior el primer div ajustándolo solo al alto de su contenido. No sé si me expliqué bien.

Comment: Perdón, `height: 100vh` del segundo div, el rojo. Tu regla quedaría así: `@media (max-width:991px){.full-height>div:nth-child(2){background:red;height:100vh}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución que se me ocurre es que uses las propiedades CSS [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) establecida a `column` sólo para los tamaños móviles (`@media (max-width: 991px)`) en el elemento `row` que contiene las columnas. Luego, en el primer elemento `div` no uses `fit-content`, mejor usas la propiedad CSS [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) establecida a `0` y en el segundo elemento la usas establecida a `1`.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.full-height{
    min-height: 100vh;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .full-height {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .full-height > div:first-child{
      flex-grow: 0;
  }
  /* Añado el color rojo de fondo al segundo hijo para enseñar el gap que se crea en medio*/
  .full-height > div:nth-child(2){
      background:red;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row full-height">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center bg-left" style="background-color:#4982fc;">
        <h4>Primer DIV</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 text-center px-0">
        <h4>Segundo DIV</h4>
        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

De esta forma, cuando estás en dispositivos móviles, la dirección de crecimiento es vertical y los elementos ocuparán el espacio completo del contenedor establecido a `100vh`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Mis respetos Mauricio, sin dudas Flex es muy completo, debo profundizar más en el tema.

Comment: Parece justo lo que necesitaba, Mauricio! Muchísimas gracias. Hasta mañana no podré probarlo en mi página pero por el ejemplo se ve exactamente como quería. Y tan solo tres líneas ... Al igual que Jheyman, creo que voy a tener que investigar esto del Flex! Un saludo y gracias a ambos por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Por fin he podido probarlo en la página real, va perfecto. De nuevo muchísimas gracias, llevaba demasiado tiempo perdido con ese problema!